# How does kafka streams compute watermarks?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Does Kafka Streams internally compute watermarks? Is it possible to observe the result of a window (only) when it completes (i.e. when watermark passes end of window)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka Streams does not use watermarks internally, but a new feature in 2.1.0 lets you observe the result of a window when it closed. It's called `Suppressed`, and you can read about it in the docs: [Window Final Results](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#window-final-results):

```
KGroupedStream<UserId, Event> grouped = ...;
grouped
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(1)).grace(ofMinutes(10)))
    .count()
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
```

Comment: So the individual processors uses the event timestamps (plus the lag) to decide when the window is complete and emit the results once? If theres another window operator downstream, which timestamps would it use to determine that window is complete?

Comment: Yes, once. And " If theres another window operator downstream, which timestamps would it use to determine that window is complete? " — I'm not sure, I've never windowed a windowed stream... will have to think about that.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Kafka Streams internally compute watermarks?

No. Kafka Streams follows a *continuous update* processing model that does not require watermarks. You can find more details about this online:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/watermarks-tables-event-time-dataflow-model/
- https://www.confluent.io/resources/streams-tables-two-sides-same-coin

> Is it possible to observe the result of a window (only) when it completes (i.e. when watermark passes end of window)?

You can observe of result of a window at any point in time. Either via subscribing to the result changelog stream via for example `KTable#toStream()#foreach()` (ie, a push based approach), or via [Interactive Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) that let you query the result window actively (ie, a pull based approach).

As mentioned by @Dmitry, for the push based approach, you can also use `suppress()` operator if you are only interested in a window's final result.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting insights. Continuous table update model looks very interesting. For the push based model it uses a simple event timestamp (plus a lag) to determine when to consider the window as completed, so looks like a subset of the full blown watermark model.

Comment: For the push based model, you get a notification for *every* update to the window, even if the window end time is not reached yet. You can use `suppress()` to get a similar behavior as with watermarks.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: If a stream is re-keyed into an intermediate stream, how is the timestamp of a message computed? eg: the intermediate stream partition may receive events out-of-order even though the "source" stream-partition has monotonic timestamps

Comment: The timestamp is not recomputed, but the original input record timestamp is preserved. It's correct, that it might result in out-of-order data, even if the original input topic does not contain out-of-order data.